# Verify Spree promotion coupon from an external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, spree-3.1

I want to apply a coupon to my spree application but the coupon should be verified from an external API

I searched through the docs as well as tutorials but I haven't found anything which can help me

The requirement is something like this:

- I am selling a product and I want to give a discount of 10% to members of some organization.
- On payment page, the user will enter his email address and I want to verify that email from API provided by organization

I am referring this right now

1 . [**`Promotions`**](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/user/promotions.html)

**EDIT:**

I am currently looking into Promotion rules and Promotion Handlers

- [**`Registering a New Rule`**](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/promotions.html#registering-a-new-rule)
- [**`Promotion Handler - Coupon`**](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/promotion_handler/coupon.rb)

Comment: What coupon API do you use?

Comment: It's an api provided by organisation that will tell us if user has their membership or not

Comment: So when a user enters their email, you want to hit an API and get back a true or false answer to whether or not this user gets the promotion?

Comment: You're going to have to write custom code for this. Spree supports writing custom promotion rules. See the doc here: https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/guides/content/developer/core/promotions.md#registering-a-new-rule

Comment: @mroach I am currently looking into the same will let you know once done

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new user rule.
In `app/models/spree/promotion/rules/organisational_user.rb`,

```
module Spree
  class Promotion
    module Rules
      class OrganisationalUser < PromotionRule
        def applicable?(promotable)
          promotable.is_a?(Spree::Order)
        end

        def eligible?(order, options = {})
          # hit external API to verify user existence
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Register this rule,
In `spree.rb`,

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.config.spree.promotions.rules << Spree::Promotion::Rules::OrganisationalUser
end
```

Then add requisite view files and translation for this rule.
And that should be it. Now you can use that rule in conjunction with any other rule and action.